# Direct URL to "I'm Feeling Lucky" for images

Tags: image, url

I have a website for book reviews. I offer a link to the Amazon entry of the books. I discovered after a bit of research that the direct URL for Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" is:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=TITLE+AUTHOR+amazon&btnI=745

Which works magic because then I don't have to manually include the Amazon link in my database and directly links to the Amazon page (works 99.99% of the times).

I was wondering if there was an equivalent for images (whether Google or some alternative) to retrieve an image URL based on keywords only (for the purpose of getting the book cover image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be hard to parse the amazon page and get the image and link but google has an API to google books that return all informations about a book in JSON format, you can try it online on the API Explorer (the cover are on the results too). Click [here](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=books&_v=v1&_m=volumes.list&q=Crime%20and%20Punishment) to see an example (click "Execute" to run it).

Comment: fantastic! could you give me any more advice on how to use it? thanks

Comment: You can read the docs here: https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started
Here is a little script to show the data
http://jsfiddle.net/zCCGK/  (press "Run" to execute it)

(But please read the docs to see if this kind of usage is allowed)

Comment: This api might have been fantastic in 2012. So fantastic it's not here in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing for Google Images, but you might be able to use another web service to do what you want. I noticed that when you're searching for a book, the first image result isn't always the cover of it. Sometimes it's a photo of the author, sometimes it's some image from book's review, so you can hardly rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately public Google search engine doesn't support that. You should use [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to implement such feature in your application. Alternatively use [XGoogle](https://github.com/mycognitive/xgoogle) (unofficial Python wrapper to Google Search services, see [`google_dl` tool](https://github.com/mycognitive/google_dl) for example).

Other suggestions is to use:

- YQL by Yahoo (see [`yql-tables` repo at GitHub](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables) for examples).
- Use alternative search engines.

  E.g. In [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) you can type: "show image of laptop" and it'll give you the first popular picture, however you need to use [Wolfram|Alpha APIs](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) or some script (see this [ChatBot](https://github.com/Jenna3715/ChatBot) for example) to pick up the direct link.